# Uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{n}}{100+x^{2n}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence, solution-verification, sequence-of-function

[LINK FOR EXERCISE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb1xs.png)Prove that $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{
n}}{100+x^{2n}}}$$  converges uniformly for $x \in [2,\infty)$?
I know it converges uniformly, but when I tried to prove it, I get stuck when trying to reformat it into a geometric series in order to find the limit, but I know it would be better to apply *Weierstrass M-test* but the $M_n$ that I found to be larger or equal to the sum above would  be $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{x^{n}}{100+x^{n}}}$$ but I am not sure how to prove that is converges, as by ratio and root test, it doesn't work out very well.

*edit: I made a typo, the start of summation is at n=1 not n=0, as well in my exercise sheet, it said to prove that it converges uniformly , sorry about that.
*edit #2, I made another typo, for the numerator it is supposed to be $x^n$ not $x^{2n}$ sorry.

Comment: For $|x|>1$, this series diverges trivially, since its general term tends to $1$.

Comment: You say you know it converges uniformly; but this is manifestly false, as others have pointed out. So how do you "know" it? Perhaps you have copied it wrong?

Comment: @TonyK Maybe there was a mistake on the exercise sheet, but it said to prove that it converges uniformly, I will try to link an image in the post.

Comment: The image has $x^n$ in the numerator, not $x^{2n}$.

Comment: @TonyK yes I realised, that was an error on my part

Comment: @paullacher Did you read my answer to the new version of your question?

Answer (score 1):

If$$f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{100+x^{2n}},$$then$$f_n'(x)=\frac{n x^{n-1} \left(100-x^{2n}\right)}{\left(x^{2 n}+100\right)^2},$$which is negative, for every $x\geqslant2$, if $n\geqslant4$ (because then $x^{2n}\geqslant2^8=256$). So, for $N\geqslant4$, $f_n$ is decreasing and therefore$$f_n(x)\leqslant f_n(2)=\frac{2^n}{100+4^n}<\frac1{2^n}.$$But the series $\sum_{n=4}^\infty\frac1{2^n}$ converges. Therefore, your series converges uniformly, by the Weierstrass $M$ test.

Comment: thank you, but I am a bit confused, how would it go to 1, wouldn't it go to 0 as the denominator is larger than the numerator?

Comment: For really big $n$, the constant term $100$ doesnt matter, i.e. for very large $n$ we have that $x^{2n} \approx x^{2n} +100$

Comment: @paullacher: Just as a sanity check: what does $\frac{n}{n+1}$ tend to as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @TonyK it's 1 no?

Comment: @paullacher $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{100+x^{2n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{100x^{-2n}+1}=\frac11=1.$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you!

Comment: @paullacher: yes, it's $1$, of course. Even though, to quote you, "the denominator is larger than the numerator".